# As a PC, would I be able to start with a magic item in my equipment without my DM's permission?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

[I kind of asked a question about this, but I was a DM.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/206209/can-a-level-1-character-start-with-a-magic-item) Now, I'm wondering if this is true for player characters- and I don't want to have to ask my DM about this, either. Would I be able to have  a magic item without my DM giving permission?

Comment: This immediately raises the question: why would you want to do that?

Comment: @biziclop of course because you are Pun-Pun and need a magic lamp to summon a very specific being...

Answer (score 15):

#### You can’t do *anything* without the DM’s permission.

The DM’s role is described in the intro to the *Dungeon Master’s Guide*:

> And as a referee, the DM interprets the rules and decides when to abide by them and when to change them.

> You’re the DM, and you are in charge of the game.

> As a referee, the DM acts as a mediator between the rules and the players.

The DM in charge of the game, and the DM determines what character options and parameters are available for character creation. This even includes the “standard” PHB options - the DM can ban PHB character options if they want.

Speaking more generally, *the DM’s role requires that they have exhaustive knowledge of your character*. You cannot keep secrets from the DM, because they are the arbiter of the rules.

So the *only* way to start the game with a magic item is to have one given you by the DM or be permitted by the DM to play a character option that grants one (if such an option exists).

Comment: It might be worth specifying that this "anything" includes standard PHB chargen options. A DM is fully within their rights to say you can't play a dragonborn, or a Circle of the Moon druid.

Answer (score 8):

### No.

*Player's Handbook* p. 14, "Choose Equipment", and p. 143, Chapter 5: "Equipment", both assert that your starting equipment is defined by your class and background. Alternatively, you can take an equivalent in gold pieces, and purchase equipment with those from the equipment listed in Chapter 5. You can also have a free trinket from p.160-161, but that's usually not a magic item.

The equipment in Chapter 5 is non-magical equipment, not magic items.

Your DM can allow you to start with more items, or to buy magic items with your starting gold, but that's at the DM's discretion. Even then, magic items tend to be out of the reach of your starting gold. You might afford one common item, generally worth 50 to 100 gp, and that might easily be half your starting gold or more, and even then only if the DM specifically allows you to.

You could start with a magic item if you found a background or class which specifically granted one, although I don't know of any which do so.

Comment: I'd assume a potion of healing wouldn't need DM permission. I'd not expect a new PC to buy one given the cost vs. benefit.

Comment: @AllanMills technically, it *does*.

Comment: @Trish Need DM permission? If so, why? It's on the basic equipment list in the PHB.

Comment: @AllanMills You need the DM's ok to play *anything* on their table. They are the final arbiter. They can say no to anything.

Comment: I'd differentiate between things you can do by the default rules, and things you can't normally do unless the DM gives special permission. Otherwise, "ask your DM" would be the answer to every question.

Comment: @QuadraticWizard Agreed. If you need the DM's permission to do things in accordance with the basic rules, it might be time to look for a new DM. Unless they have some specific reasoning like starting the campaign after a shipwreck with no equipment.